# Edit1.text / Combobox1.selecteditem in QRLabel

Tags: delphi

Is it possible to show edit1.text data in QRlabel? I want to add items and save with quickreport. My edit field and combobox is on my main form, Quickrep is on the second form. 
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
procedure TQuickRpr1.QRLabel1Print(Sender: TObject; var Value: string);
begin
  Value := Form1.Edit1.Text
end;
```

Comment: Big thanks! And what about datetimepicker? Value := Form1.Datetimepicker1.?

Comment: If it is possible:) I want to add the seleted date to QRlabel.

Comment: Ok! i got it! `Value := FormatDateTime('dddddd', form2.DateTimePicker1.Date);`

Comment: On more thing. How can i use it with checkboxes?:)