# checkbox1.x in QRlabel?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have two checkboxes on my main Form!(checkbox1 and checkbox2) I want to add the checked checkbox captions, and save with quickreport to QRLabel. Only the checked checkbox. My Quickrep is on the second form. Thanks for the help!

```
procedure TQuickRpr1.QRLabel1Print(Sender: TObject; var Value: string);
begin

end;
```

Comment: Radio buttons would suit more perhaps.. Start with `if Form1.Checkbox1.Checked then Value := ... `

Comment: This is the same question you asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18358244/62576), just with a different control. The answer is also the same (just with a different control). Please make at least a minimal effort to learn from your questions; you should be able to figure this out yourself based on the previously provided information. StackOverflow is not a programming tutorial site, where we help you do every single task one step at a time. You should be trying to learn from information you get here and expand that knowledge in order to do more complex tasks.